# How to create a string literal type from values in an object data set?

Tags: typescript

I have a big data set that I build from data fetched from a remote source, it looks like that :

```json
[
  { id: 14, name: 'foo' },
  { id: 2, name: 'bar' },
  { id: 93, name: 'baz' },
  ...
]
```

I would like to create this type :

```js
type Name = 'foo'|'bar'|'baz'|...;
```

(from the object then)

I think it's worth noting that the object is imported from a json file :

```js
import data from './data.json'
```

I tried that

```js
type Name = typeof data[number]['name']
```

But then Typescript thinks the type is just `string`

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if you'll be able to do so due to the data being loaded from a `.json` file, but if `data` were a regular variable then you could use `as const` to achieve what you are looking for

```
const x = [
  { id: 14, name: 'foo' },
  { id: 2, name: 'bar' },
  { id: 93, name: 'baz' },
] as const // <--- use as const here

type Name = typeof x[number]["name"] // Name is 'foo' | 'bar' | 'baz'
```

Comment: Yes I already know that, that is why I mentioned about the file being imported from a json which I can't modify. Any idea of a workaround ?